# How do I refer to data class property names for Firestore queries?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a simple data class Track, then saving it as an object so that fields and values are automatically saved. This is working as intended. However later when I want to query on 1 of those property/field names, I need to provide the String value.

How do I refer to the name of that property in the data class, so that I maintain the "single source of truth" for that value, without hard coding it a second time in the query? Example uses "spotifyId":

```
data class Track(
    val spotifyId: String,
    val name: String,
    val artist: List<String>,
    val duration: String
)
```

Save a track:

```
set(trackDocRef, track)
```

Query for a track:

```
db.collection("tracks").whereEqualTo("spotifyId", "sdfgsdfswer4543w5yer345").get()
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please add screenshot of your document as well. You can try something like `Track(it.child("spotifyId").value.toString(), it.child("name").value.toString(), it.child("artist").value), it.child("duration").value.toString())` where `it` is the DataSnapshot

Comment: Unless I'm not following, the problem is still that your code example has a hardcoded reference to the "spotifyId" string name? If I change the data class definition for Track so that "spotifyId" becomes "spotifyTrackId" then:

1. When I save a Track with that data class, the Track document will automatically have a field  "spotifyTrackId"

2. When I retrieve the track and use toObject, it will successfully retrieve the Track.

3. However now that hardcoded example you've got store refers to "spotifyId"?

Comment: I've hard-coded spotifyId because that's the field name in your firestore db. That ideally shouldn't change but if it does, you need some way to reference it and pass the values to constructor as parameters.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the feedback I appreciate it. The reason that "spotifyId" is the field name in the Firestore document, is because I'm saving a Track object and Firestore is automatically creating the field names, drawn from the property names in the Track object. But later when I want to run a query in that collection I need to provide a field name and I would like to be able to refer to the exact name used in the Track class, not hardcode it in a different package which opens up the possibility of bugs. That way I am not doubling the references to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out one way of doing it, not sure how "correct" it is. I used reflection in the TracksContract object to refer to the Track model:

```
data class Track(
    val spotifyId: String,
    val name: String,
    val artist: List<String>,
    val duration: String
)
```

Single reference to Track model via TracksContract:

```
object TracksContract {

    internal const val COLLECTION_NAME = "Tracks"

    object Fields {
        val SPOTIFY_ID = Track::spotifyId.name
        val NAME = Track::name.name
        val ARTIST = Track::artist.name
        val DURATION = Track::duration.name
    }
}
```

now if I need to run the query based on that spotifyId, I refer to through the TracksContract:

```
db.collection(TracksContract.COLLECTION_NAME)
    .whereEqualTo(TracksContract.Fields.SPOTIFY_ID, "ID_VALUE")
    .get()
```

Finally if I decide to change the property names in the Track model then the TracksContract will show a compiler error, and I can change the name and refactor references from there if I want to.